# JavaScript Shorthand for multiple items

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is it possible to use a JavaScript shorthand if statement on the code below?

With either `(sel>=0)? true: false;` or `(sel>=0)? ~~(true)`?

```
var sel=+this.selectedIndex - 3;

(sel>=0) ? item1.className="show" item2.className="hide"  items.innerHTML="My Item 3A" : item1.className="hide" item2.className="show" item3.innerHTML="My Item 3B";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

```
sel >= 0 ? (item1.className="show", item2.className="hide", items.innerHTML="My Item 3A") : (item1.className="hide", item2.className="show", item3.innerHTML="My Item 3B");
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
sel >= 0 ? 
(function() { item1.className="show"; item2.className="hide"; items.innerHTML="My Item 3A"; })() : 
(function() { item1.className="hide"; item2.className="show"; item3.innerHTML="My Item 3B"; })();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap it in an anonymous function !

Comment: How will this help answer the question?